# How to set coordinate for my checkers game in Android App

Tags: android

I'm new bird for the Android App, hope can get teach from expert. I'm now doing the checkers board game for my final project. I face the problem is, how do I set the coordinator for my board boxes with using the image button?
Do I am correct for using that way?

Comment: Can't see any code. Please, edit your question!

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `GridView` to contain your board squares. Then you could simply bind an array of your backing checker square objects to the grid, and create your own `BaseAdapter` to display an `ImageButton` in each grid cell.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a custom `View` and set it as the content background.
ie.

```
CheckerBoard board = new CheckerBoard(this);
setContentView(board);
```

In the above code, `CheckerBoard` extends `View`. Within the `CheckerBoard` class, you could have the view divided into an 8 x 8 grid programmatically using the width and height passed in. Then you could have that view paint your grid, while also binding each area to a two-dimensional array. It's kind of complicated to explain the hierarchy I have in mind, but check out this mockup:

```
public class CheckerBoard extends View {

     @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);

        // A checkerboard is a square; this keeps the view's 
        // length and width the same size.
        width = (height > width) ? height : width;
        height = (height > width) ? width : height;

        this.setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        //Log.i("VolumeGauge", "Size changed to " + w + "x" + h);

        // This is where you divide up the view into 64
        // pieces and paint them.
        generateBackground();
    }

    Other methods here…

}
```

There is a LOT of stuff that goes into making this work properly, but the best resource I can give you is this: 
http://mindtherobot.com/blog/272/android-custom-ui-making-a-vintage-thermometer/

It walks you through the process of creating a custom `View`.
Once you have the `CheckerBoard` created, it's just a matter of mapping each square to a two-dimensional boolean array (each element will be `true` if it is occupied by a playing piece), and then tracking the user's touch input on the screen.

Comment: Hi Thanks so much guys, really appreciate for it!